# Watching Add to Cart Event - quote item id is empty

Tags: magento-1.7, event-observer, quote

I am trying to catch the event that fires once an item is added to the cart. I'm currently watching the following event: checkout_cart_product_add_after

According to magento source this event is fired after everything is done to the Quote. but when i access the cart id and the quote id the values are empty:

```
$quoteItem = $observer->getQuoteItem();
$quote_item_id = $quoteItem->getItemId();
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
$quote_id= $cart->getQuoteId();
```

The above returns empty for both ids when there are no items in the cart, if the cart already has an item the cart id has value but the quote_item_id doesn't.

Notice this has been asked before, but the question was never resolved, and the discussion ended up straying from this issue. I need the quote_item_id.

Comment: try with `$quoteItem = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem();`

Comment: Same thing, the id comes empty.

Comment: Add this in your observer `Mage::log($quoteItem)` and see in `var/log/system.log` how the quote item looks like. Maybe you get an idea from there.

Comment: that is a huge amount of information, i'll easily get lost in it

Comment: :). Try to log then `Mage::getLog($quoteItem->getData())` maybe you have more luck with it.

Comment: =D still too big, i tried Mage::getLog($quoteItem->debug()) and i notice that there is no itemid in the resulting array. There seems to be an item_id in the stock_item element inside the quoteitem but i'm not even sure what that is. Edit: this isn't it this value is allways the same

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Don't do this.

Your problem is, that the cart is not yet saved, have a look here:

https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php#L201-L206

```
public function addAction()
{
// ...
        $cart->addProduct($product, $params); // <-- you are inside this method
        if (!empty($related)) {
            $cart->addProductsByIds(explode(',', $related));
        }

        $cart->save(); // here is the saving, and therefore after this line,
                       //  quote and items have an id
// ...
        Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_add_product_complete',
            array('product' => $product, 'request' => $this->getRequest(), 'response' => $this->getResponse())
        );
```

What you want is to listen on `checkout_cart_add_product_complete`

If you want to know which items where added this round, just flag them in `checkout_cart_product_add_after` like `$quoteItem->setIsNew()` then you can check in `checkout_cart_add_product_complete` for `$quoteItem->getIsNew()`

Comment: I figured that would be it, problem is that event only sends the product out. Is it a good idea to get the cart from session and get the last of the allitems array? i worry that there might be some kind of race condition

Comment: Edited the answer. You need to flag your quote items, then let magento save them, then you know your quote item and the product :)

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt is there an event to be triggered while updating the cart?

Comment: yes, many, you can just hook into the dispatchEvent and check it: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/9155/217 And make sure to read the comment from ben!

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `checkout_cart_product_add_after` event with this:

`$observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem()->getProduct()->getData()`

The data returned looks similar to this:

```
Array
(
    [store_id] => 1
    [entity_id] => 1
    [entity_type_id] => 4
    [attribute_set_id] => 4
    [type_id] => simple
    [sku] => TESTSKU
    [has_options] => 0
    [required_options] => 0
    [created_at] => 2015-02-10T12:11:50-05:00
    [updated_at] => 2015-02-10 17:18:47
    [name] => Demo Product
    [url_key] => demo-product
    [country_of_manufacture] => 
    [msrp_enabled] => 2
    [msrp_display_actual_price_type] => 4
    [meta_title] => 
    [meta_description] => 
    [image] => no_selection
    [small_image] => no_selection
    [thumbnail] => no_selection
    [custom_design] => 
    [page_layout] => 
    [options_container] => container1
    [gift_message_available] => 
    [url_path] => demo-product.html
    [weight] => 1.0000
    [price] => 12.9900
    [special_price] => 
    [msrp] => 
    [status] => 1
    [visibility] => 4
    [tax_class_id] => 2
    [is_recurring] => 0
    [description] => It's a sample product, what do you want?
    [short_description] => It's a demo product
    [meta_keyword] => 
    [custom_layout_update] => 
    [news_from_date] => 
    [news_to_date] => 
    [special_from_date] => 
    [special_to_date] => 
    [custom_design_from] => 
    [custom_design_to] => 
    [group_price] => Array
        (
        )

    [group_price_changed] => 0
    [media_gallery] => Array
        (
            [images] => Array
                (
                )

            [values] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [tier_price] => Array
        (
        )

    [tier_price_changed] => 0
    [stock_item] => Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item Object
    (
        // Crazy recursion happens here
    )
    [is_in_stock] => 1
    [is_salable] => 1
    [website_ids] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )
    [cart_qty] => 1
    [qty] => 1
    [stick_within_parent] => 
    [customer_group_id] => 0
    [final_price] => 
)
```

This was tested on Magento 1.9.1.0, but from what I can tell, this should work on 1.7

Answer (score 2):

you can use following event

```
sales_quote_item_set_product
```

and get item id in observer like this.

```
$quote_item = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem();
$item_id = $quote_item->getItemId();
```

Comment: This event is called for every quote item every time the cart is built, not only when an item is added to the cart.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by calling save on $cart and on quoteItem. Not selecting this as correct since i'm not sure this is the best method.

Fabian Blechschmidt solution is much better, use that one.