# checkout_cart_add_product_complete get quote item

Tags: cart, event-observer

I'm trying to perform an action after i add a product to my cart.

I tried the observer 
checkout_cart_product_add_after
but this does not enter a new line in the quote until after, thus my quote item is empty.

I need to have the line item created for the quote.

So i thought i would use "checkout_cart_add_product_complete" and this does create a line item in the quote, but i don't know what the new line item entity_id is from the "checkout_cart_add_product_complete", i tried looking at the object but it is way to big for me to find it....

Anyway so all i want after adding a product to the cart, is get the new line item id, this DOES NOT have to be from my observer object if not possible...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested some code here, and I am finding that `checkout_cart_product_add_after` does include the quote item, after it has been added:

```
$item = $observer->getQuoteItem();
$quote = $item->getQuote();

echo $item->getId();
```

Comment: Well i had tried that, and again, i don't get a line item id, unless the item already existed in the cart and i added another one...

Comment: You could try doing `$item->save();`, to see if that will then set the item id.

Comment: that could work, that is just not what i want or need to do, and it would create lots of non needed items in the ccart

Comment: I may be missing something, but I believe that this item will be saved anyway, and this is just making it happen sooner. Maybe, would you revisit your question to add some more details and clarify? That would help.

Comment: See http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10662/watching-add-to-cart-event-quote-item-id-is-empty on how to get the quote item ID after the item has been saved.