# Event checkout_cart_add_product_complete - Get Quote Item (follow up question)

Tags: cart, event-observer

I'm observing the c`heckout_cart_add_product_complete` event and need to get the added quote item.

There was a previous post on this issue with a suggestion to flag the new quote item in `checkout_cart_product_add_after` and then access it in `checkout_cart_add_product_complete`.

My question is on a basic level - how exactly do I implement this solution if I only get passed the product in `checkout_cart_add_product_complete`?

Link to previous post: [Watching Add to Cart Event - quote item id is empty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10662/watching-add-to-cart-event-quote-item-id-is-empty/10668#10668?newreg=8d59b6a91efe41fc95954b0adbbcb251)

Answer (score 1):

You get the quote by:

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
```

then you have access to all items:

```
$quote->getAllItems()
```

And follow the instructions of the [original answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/10670/243)

Answer (score -1):

```
public function yourObserverFunction(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {     
    $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
    var_dump($product->getId());
    var_dump($product->getName());die;
}
```