# quote item price information missing in checkout_cart_product_add_after event

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, quoteitem

I have implemented an observer for `checkout_cart_product_add_after`. I am retrieving the quote item by

```
$item = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem();
```

However, I noticed, that any of the functions to retrieve the item's current price simply return `NULL`. I can't even access its ID!

On further inspection I see that the quote item only has the following data attributes set:

```
quote_id
store_id
product
product_id
product_type
sku
name
weight
tax_class_id
base_cost
is_recurring
is_qty_decimal
is_nominal
qty_to_add
qty
qty_options
```

Attributes like `price`, `base_price`, `custom_price` etc. are completely missing.

I am also observing the `checkout_cart_update_items_after` event, where I get the quote item in a different way:

```
$cart = $observer->getEvent()->getCart();
$data = $observer->getEvent()->getInfo();

foreach( $data as $itemId => $itemInfo )
{
    if( $item = $cart->getQuote()->getItemById( $itemId ) )
    {
        $item = $item->getParentItem() ?: $item;
        …
    }
}
```

In this case, all the relevant data is present.

Can anyone tell me, why the price data is missing for quote items in the `checkout_cart_product_add_after` event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, it seems this is the correct answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/10670/37461

I have changed the event to `checkout_cart_add_product_complete` accordingly and changed the code in my observer to

```
$product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
$quote = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
$item = $quote->getItemByProduct( $product );
```

to get the quote item with all details.